# Present perfect tense - counting

Tags: present-perfect

I ate two hamburgers yesterday and I ate three hamburgers today.

In this context, right after I ate the fifth hamburger, could I say "I've eaten five hamburgers now"? or "I've just eaten five hamburgers"?

Comment: You could only say  "I've eaten five hamburgers now" if you had never had one at all until yesterday!

Comment: I worry about Faint's health.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I've eaten [a total of] five hamburgers now"? ✅

This sentence suggests five burgers were eaten within 24 hours or even at a single sitting. It could also imply that the speaker has eaten only five burgers in their entire life, maybe there are no hamburger joints in the area/country where he lives, so each time is a little celebration but without greater context I would think it was referring to a single day.

> "I **ate** two hamburgers **yesterday** and three today" ✅

The time reference "yesterday" fixes the event firmly in the past. And even though "today" may not be over, the sentence above strongly suggests that the speaker is not going to eat a fourth hamburger. However,

> "I've eaten three hamburgers today [so far]" ✅

leaves the possibility that there is enough time for the speaker to eat a fourth or even a fifth burger.

If the speaker wants to say they have eaten a total of five burgers then they must use the preposition *since*

> ***Since yesterday*** *I've eaten five hamburgers*

Comment: Thank you, but my question is quite different. I ate the first hamburger (1:00) I ate the second hamburger (5:00) I ate the third hamburger (9:00) I said "I've just eaten three hamburgers" (9:00)

Comment: @Faint You edited your question and added `"I've just eaten five hamburgers"` but this means you ate five burgers in one sitting. I'm sorry but does (1.00) (5:00) (9:00) mean 1 pm, 5 pm and 9pm? The five burgers were eaten at different intervals, they were not eaten at the same time because "just" means very recently.

Comment: Yes it is p.m..

Comment: The reference to "within 24 hours" makes no sense to me. Depending on exact context, to have "just" done something could be within the last minute, or the past week (or even longer).